# Is there a way to calculate the amount of data stored by a particular user in a relational MySQL table

Tags: mysql, database, algorithm

Is there a way to calculate the amount of data stored *for* a particular user in a relational MySQL table?

User - just a simple key field in the relational database which is foreign key to other tables.

Other tables may have their primary key they may also be others foreign key.

I want to calculate the amount of data stored for that particular key field throughout the database:
Is it possible? What would be the logic?

Answer (score 1):

```
  select sum(len(cast(column1 as varbinary))+ ....) as amount, user group by user
```